# search and compare a string with an array of strings

Tags: c, string, search, compare

This is the code I have

```
const char *s[5];={"abcd","efgh","ijkl","mnop","qrst"};
char a[4];
while (1)
      {
      scanf("%4s",&a);

      //compare a with s array

      if(/*a exists in s*/)
      printf("it is ok");

      if(/*a does not exist in s*/)
      printf("it is not ok");
}
```

For example when I type "dcba" I want to see "it is not ok". When I type "efgh" I want to see "it is ok".

Comment: `scanf` expects a `char *` with `%4s`, not a `char(*)[4]`. It's also important how you do the comparison.

Comment: you can edit all of it to reach what i need.

Comment: when `"%4s"`, need`char a[5];`

Comment: scanf takes a pointer to the variable, `int a;` would be `scanf("%d", &i);`. However as char a in your case points to were the array begins, it is used without the reference, `scanf("%s", a)` just like that!

Comment: `bsearch` can use if array is sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First declare your arrays `a` as

```
char a[5];
```

use [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html#tag_16_142) to input string (do not use `scanf`), then use [`strcmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcmp.html#tag_16_569) or [`strncmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncmp.html#tag_16_579) function to compare the two string/(literals).

Comment: I forgot to say my compiler is CodeVision AVR and I am limited to use all C functions like that you say

Comment: Do you mean you are not allowed to use `string.h` functions?

Answer (score 0):

If you were using C++ and the `std::string` class, you could use a `std::vector<string>` and the `std::find` from `<algorithm>` and find your string.

Since you are using C-style strings, search your reference book for `strcmp` for comparing an item in the container with a C-style string variable.